# Is HTTP PUT access required for uploading to SharePoint via the SaveBinaryDirect method?

Tags: sharepoint, csom

We have developed a .NET console application to do file uploading to a SharePoint 2016 document library.   The application was built using the `Microsoft.SharePoint2016.CSOM` library, with file uploading using on the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect()` method call.

Based on results from a web vulnerability scanning, there was a request that the “HTTP PUT method” should be disabled in IIS. However after some testing, we found that

1. If “HTTP PUT” is **enabled**, the file upload is successful
2. If “HTTP PUT” is **disabled**, the console application would return a 404 error from the file uploading step

We would like to confirm whether “HTTP PUT method” is ***necessary (and cannot be disabled)*** for the SharePoint CSOM `SaveBinaryDirect()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Fiddler to monitor the request, you can find it's PUT request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to access the SharePoint services(rest/web) the user should be authenticated. Its not like anyone can upload a file. People can use `POST` instead of `PUT` for uploading etc. So I am not sure what type of quality check you are using.

These are the out of the box services SharePoint is providing and I have seen very big enterprises using it without the changes you have suggested.